# Can top level classes be pickled and unpickled (documentation wrong?)

Tags: python, pickle

The documentation linked below seems to say that top level classes can be pickled, as well as their instances. But based on the answers to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34261379/3904031) it seem not to be correct. In the script I posted the pickle accepts the class object and writes a file, but this is not useful.

THIS IS MY QUESTION: Is this documentation wrong, or is there something more subtle I don't understand? Also, should pickle be generating some kind of error message in this case?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled,

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - None, True, and False
> - integers, long integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
> - normal and Unicode strings
> - tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects
> - functions defined at the top level of a module
> - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - **classes that are defined at the top level of a module**  ( *my bold* )
> - instances of such classes whose **dict** or the result of calling **getstate**() > is picklable (see section The pickle protocol for details).

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation clearly explains what it means to pickle a class, and your quarrel is with whether that's what it *ought* to mean to pickle a class.

Comment: No quarrel intended. I am trying to understand what exactly it means to "pickle a class." If it is clear to you, could you post something as an answer? I originally thought that I could recover the definition so I could create more instances, but that seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a class that is *defined at the top level of a module*:

**foo.py**:

```
class Foo(object): pass
```

Then running a separate script,

**script.py**:

```
import pickle
import foo


with open('/tmp/out.pkl', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(foo.Foo, f)

del foo

with open('/tmp/out.pkl', 'r') as f:
    cls = pickle.load(f)

print(cls)
```

prints

```
<class 'foo.Foo'>
```

---

Note that the pickle file, `out.pkl`, merely contains *strings* which name the defining module and the name of the class. It does not store the definition of the class:

```
cfoo
Foo
p0
.
```

Therefore, *at the time of unpickling* the defining module, `foo`, must contain the definition of the class. If you delete the class from the defining module

```
del foo.Foo
```

then you'll get the error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Foo'
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, that was my experience in my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34261379/3904031) a few days ago. So I'm getting closer to understanding, can you help me understand what is the utility of pickling a class without its definition. Is it along the lines of just managing the name of the class?

Comment: See comment by @justhalf below that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34262880/3904031)

Comment: @uhoh: Pickling a class is essentially the same as storing the name of the class (as a string) and the name of the defining module (as a string). If you were to just store the class name and module name as strings, then you could use `module = __import__(module_name)`, `cls = getattr(module, class_name)` instead of pickling. I tend to only use pickling (implicitly) when using the multiprocessing module -- since all objects passed through `Queue`s get pickled. For long-term persistence, I tend to use other mechanisms like `JSON` or a database to avoid version or language incompatibility.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain even further. This is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It's totally possible to pickle a class instance in python… while also saving the code to reconstruct the class and the instance's state.  If you want to hack together a solution on top of `pickle`, or use a "trojan horse" `exec` based method here's how to do it:

[How to unpickle an object whose class exists in a different namespace (python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238837/how-to-unpickle-an-object-whose-class-exists-in-a-different-namespace-python?rq=1)

Or, if you use `dill`, you have a `dump` function that already knows how to store a class instance, the class code, and the instance state:

[How to recover a pickled class and its instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261379/how-to-recover-a-pickled-class-and-its-instances/34397001#34397001)

[Pickle python class instance plus definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726183/pickle-python-class-instance-plus-definition/28095208#28095208)

I'm the `dill` author, and I created `dill` in part to be able to ship class instances and class methods across `multiprocessing`.

[Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> when using python's multiprocessing Pool.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma/21345273#21345273)

Comment: Thanks @Mike. The question refers to the pickle module proper and its documentation. Now I see that the term "pickling" is can be a more broadly used to other pickle-based and pickle-like procedures. Good to collect these links together here.

Comment: Understood… Note that my first link shows how to do exactly what `dill` does, but only using the `pickle` module.  If you register a serialization method for classes, then classes can serialize.  The docs are with regard to `pickle`, without any user extensions using `copyreg`.